# iOS permissions for user location

Tags: ios, swift

I am just creating an iOS app that needs to get the user location.

I have included the needed keys and values into info.plist like shown in the screenshot:

[image]

but when running the app there is a message in the debugger:

```
2020-04-25 18:51:16.395466+0200 Jogua[23008:1151035] This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain both “NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription” and “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription” keys with string values explaining to the user how the app uses this data
```

Do I need to change anything else in the code?

EDIT

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    determineMyCurrentLocation()
}

func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")

     self.defaults.set(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, forKey: "mi_latitud")

    print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    self.defaults.set(userLocation.coordinate.longitude, forKey: "mi_longitud")

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Error \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you ask for location permissions please?

Comment: @KarloA.López, just done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your debugger says, you are missing one entry in your `info.plist`. It can be misleading because the name the console prints, is not the actual key name inside `info.plist`.

You added:

```
Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Privacy - Location Usage Description
Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
```

What you need according to the debugger is:

```
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
```

What you need to add in your case:

```
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
```